# Pointer being freed was not allocated - but why wasn't it?

Tags: memory-management, objective-c++

```
- (void)sendConfirmationMessage
{
    UInt8 *data = new UInt8[3];
    data[BYTE_SENDER_ADDRESS] = 0xFF;
    data[BYTE_MESSAGE_ID]     = 0x0C;
    data[BYTE_DATA_LENGTH]    = 0;

    CustomMessage *message = new BHCustomMessage();
    message->setDataWithSize(data, 3);  
    [self sendMessage:message];

    delete[] data; // malloc: *** error for object 0x1569d210: pointer being freed was not allocated
    delete message;
}
```

In the code above I am getting the malloc error specified on the delete[] data line.

Sorry if this is an embarrassingly simple question, but: Why wasn't the data pointer allocated? It was my understanding that the new call would do just that, thus requiring it to be deleted afterwards.

Thanks

Comment: what happens in setDataWithSize?

Comment: It seems the size is constant (3), not a variable, then why allocating on the heap?

Comment: You're most likely overwriting the `data` variable. Compare the value immediately after allocation with the one you delete.

Comment: Possibly one of `BYTE_SENDER_ADDRESS`, `BYTE_MESSAGE_ID` or `BYTE_DATA_LENGTH` is outside the range [0..2] so you're writing outside your heap cell, corrupting a guard word used by the heap manager?